# Creating local Drupal site with Acquia - 404 errors

Tags: drupal, http-status-code-404, local, acquia

I'm currently in the process of trying to create a local version of my Drupal site with Acquia, and I've completed the full installation and import process. When I got to the URL for the install, the homepage presents absolutely perfectly, but every other page gives me a basic 404 error, telling me the page does not exist of the server.

Does anyone have any past experience with this that can she some light on what's going on? It would be massively appreciated!

Thanks, Graeme

Comment: What i think is clean urls is not enabled in the web server.Try this <sitename/?q=user>

Comment: Along {prem-anand](http://stackoverflow.com/users/2124269/prem-anand) suggstion, what happens when you go to <sitename>?q=/admin/config/search/clean-urls (you might have to go to ?q=user first to authenticate with Drupal)